# Vertical SeekBar looks strange on some devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-seekbar, android-layout-weight, android-vertical-seekbar

I am trying to get vertical SeekBar to work on all devices. On some it is showing properly: 
[image] but on others not : [image] , [image] .

I made vertical SeekBar with this trick:

```
<Relative Layout
   ...
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="18dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekbar_btn1"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@null"
            android:max="100"
            android:rotation="270"
            android:splitTrack="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The SeekBar's thumb position can be fixed if I set `FrameLayout`'s `layout_width` and `SeekBar`'s `layout_height` respectively (actual SeekBar's width) to a bigger value, but then the SeekBar gets too far from the right edge, which I don't want.

The SeekBar is included in a "button" view (16 of them in 4x4 Linear Layouts with weights) so I am not able to set `SeekBar`'s `layout_width` (which is actually height) dynamically. I fixed the value to `90dp` and I am wondering if this is the root cause of the problem and how I should tackle it.

How can I make the SeekBar look the same on different devices?